# Can't get Text value from Control Template

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have re-styled a textbox using a control template. The styling works well but I cannot now get the text value from the textbox programatically after it has been changed in the textbox.

Here is how I use the style:

```
     <TextBox
        x:Name="KernTextBox"
        Style="{StaticResource MediumTextBoxStyle}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        MinLines="1"
        MaxLines="5"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        TextChanged="TextChanged"
        />
```

Here is what does not work.

```
  get { return KernTextBox.Text; }
```

Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="MediumTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonText"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Rectangle 
                        x:Name="ButtonRectangle" 
                        Stroke="Transparent" 
                        UseLayoutRounding="False" 
                        Fill="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
                    </Rectangle>

                    <TextBox 
                        x:Name="ButtonText" 
                        Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Margin="2 0"
                        TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                        MinLines="{TemplateBinding MinLines}"
                        MaxLines="{TemplateBinding MaxLines}"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"
                        Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"
                        >
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Final working style:

```
<Style 
    x:Key="TextBoxStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter
        Property="Foreground"
        Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter
        Property="FontSize"
        Value="18" />
    <Setter 
        Property="CaretBrush"
        Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border 
                    Name="Border"
                    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1" >
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you place a textbox inside a textbox? Checkout the original style and [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of a textbox and modify it from there. My guess is, the textbox uses a TextBoxView(hidden in the Scrollviewer) internally and the Text property is not bound via TemplateBinding, but calculated between these internal classes. So maybe thats the reason why you can't bind your text property to the textbox text in your control template.

Comment: If I wanted to style something around every textbox but not have to style up a full textbox, I would also do exactly what has been done here.

Comment: @Andy well, still not a good idea. How about a UserControl? Or, just take the original style and modify it, a normal textbox controltemplate is pretty short. But placing a textbox in a textbox is a pretty strange "hack" imho.

Comment: I took your advice and re-wrote the style to remove the textbox. All now working. I have added the style to my Question.

Answer (score 1):

In your sytle, when you're binding the internal Text property to the Template Text property, add the update source trigger `PropertyChanged` , then you'll get the text updating even when you've not lost focus.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The reason your method of styling a textbox wasn't quite working is because by default the text property won't update it's bound property until focus is removed from the control. I'm guessing that you're trying to use the Text property inside the TextChanged event which at that point hasn't removed focus from the TextBox.

The addition I've suggested to your Text binding will force the property to update every time the text changes and will do it just before the TextChanged event is raised.